# calling functions with or without braces scope question

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery scripts i often see functions called like this:

```
var somefunction = function(){
  $(this).doseomething()
}

$(someelement).click( somefunction );
```

Inside somefunction `this` seams to refer to the the clicked element. If the braces are used to call the function `this` does not refare to the clicked element.

Personally i don't like it. I like to see if something used in my code is a function or not. I prefere to pass `this` as argument. This is how i done it until now:

```
var somefunction = function($clickedLink){
  $clickedLink.doseomething()
}

$(someelement).click(function(){ somefunction($(this)) });
```

Why can i access the refared element if i don't use the braces? And is it a good practice in general to call functions without braces? Does it has an influence on the performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the braces, it's that any function used as an event handler, and the way jQuery calls event handlers (same is true in vanilla JavaScript), the context of that function is going to be the element that the event is firing on.

To be a bit clearer on the other point, you're not **calling** the function without parenthesis, you're passing a reference to the function.  For example, this says "here's the function to run when the event happens":

```
$(someelement).click( somefunction );
```

The other method you have does the same thing, just with more overhead of an extra anonymous function:

```
$(someelement).click(function(){ somefunction($(this)); });
```

The `function() { ... }` is what you're passing to run (it's an anonymous function, rather than your named one).   It's still not until the click event does `somefunction` actually get *called*.

---

You can do it either way, but they're not equivalent, when you pass a function directly, `this` is the element and the first argument is the [`event` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)...which you often need to stop propagation or prevent default behavior correctly.

Comment: but why is `this` not refering to the clicket element if i call the function with the braces?

Comment: @meo - because you're not calling the function with the same context,  to do that you need to maintain the context, like this: `$(someelement).click(function(){ somefunction.call(this, $(this)); });`...but you see how verbose that is compared to `$(someelement).click( somefunction );` :)

Comment: thank you for the explenation. But if i take my first exmple and just add the braces when i call some function, `this` is not the trigger element :/. Thats why i was thinking it had something to do with the braces.

Comment: @meo - That's because when you do that, you're calling it *immediately*, not *when the click happens*, and `this` refers to whatever it is at the time, if you're in a `document.ready` handler it's `document`, if you're outside it's likely `window`.

Comment: Because jQuery internally ensures that `this` refers to the clicked element when invoking the  event handler. You can simulate this yourself by calling the function by using `call` or `apply`. I.e. `somefunction.call(document.getElementById('yourElementId'));`

Comment: how it comes you awnser all my questions :) Your a deer thank you!